# How to refresh JTable after adding new entry

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` populated from the data structure `List<String>`. Also I have a button "Create New Field" that is used to create new entries in List. I can add new entry to `List<String>`, however I don't know how to refresh `JTable` after adding new entry.

Comment: Are you using a custom `TableModel` implementation or a default one like `DefaultTableModel`?

Comment: @Klausos Klausos question of this nature is quite offen asked, by default are closed as off topics, is there some problem to search here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `tableModel.fireTableDataChanged()`. Or if only a very small part (i.e. one cell) has been updated in the table: `tableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(x,y)`.

According to the comments you need to write your own small `TableModel`.

- Derive from `AbstractTableModel`
- Pass your list to the constructor of your table mdoel
- Implement required methods accordingly
- getRowCount returns `list.size()`
- getColumnCount returns 1
- getValueAt returns `list.item(row)`
- Use that table model instead of DefaultTableModel
- If you updated the list, use `fireTableDataChanged()`

Comment: I wrote this code, but it does not do the job:
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
table = new JTable(tableModel);
addNewFieldToData();
tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();

Comment: Okay, looks like you're not adding the data to the table model but to your `List<string>`. I guess this is not the best thing to do. You can either use the observer pattern (doesn't help too much here) or you need to repopulate the table model from the list after each list change. Better to add the data to the table model instead of the `List<string>` or write your own table model.

Comment: Could you please provide a short sketch?

Comment: In that case it is better to write your own small table model as described above. Then you add the data simply to the list and use the fire*()-methods accordingly.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos `Observer Pattern` this solution is an observer pattern, if you are using default table model you only have to use `addRow` method this will notify listeners. If you use a an implementation of `AbstractTableModel` then if you insert rows you have to use `fireTableRowsUpdated` if you change only a cell fireTableCellUpdated` and so on.. for more information [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html)

Comment: fireTableDataChanged() is wrong notifier, can reset all custom renderers/editors, there are implemented proper notifiers for every of possible events

Answer (score 1):

1.I have made a new project in that i have selected a new frame and drag a table,a label, a text field and a button from the swing controls to your frame.

2.create a table in back end

3.Download rs2xml jar file from this link
[Download rs2xml.jar](http://fvmproject.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9/trunk/rs2xml.jar)

Add it to the project library

4.Then connect MySQL

5.Then create a update function type the following code...

```
rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from details");
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

6.In the buttons action event type the following and call the update function.

```
Object name=jTextField1.getText();
String sql="insert into details (name) values('"+name+"')";
int  resultset=statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

You can follow this tutorial:---

[How to refresh jTable after adding new entry](http://tut.julfi.com/refresh-jtable-insert-delete-update-data-java-netbeans-id/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the observer pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Your table model should be an observer to your list. So that when you list data changes the table will be updated.

Comment: This is not really useful.. a list doesn't implements any kind of `observer pattern` so you have to create a wrapper class that has a list inside.. and in other words this is the `tableModel`